# Change dictionary values from int to string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, int

This is what my dictionary looks like.

```
phoneBook = {"Skywalker": 55511243, "Solo": 55568711, "Vader": 55590858}
```

I need to change each phonenumber into a string and add `"+1-"` in front of it. But, I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a simple dictionary comprehension:

```
r = {k: "+1-{}".format(v) for k,v in phoneBook.items()}
```

Where `"+1-{}".format(v)` converts to a string and prepends `+1-` to it. Similarly you could use `"+1-" + str(v)` as noted in the other answer but I *personally* find it less readable.

```
print(r)
{'Skywalker': '+1-55511243', 'Solo': '+1-55568711', 'Vader': '+1-55590858'}
```

Alternatively, if you want to do it *in-place*, i.e not create a new dictionary as comprehensions do, iterate *over the keys*<sup>*</sup> and update the values:

```
for k in phoneBook:
    phoneBook[k] = "+1-{}".format(phoneBook[k])
```

<sup>*Iterating over the keys only is important, if you iterate over both keys and values you'll get odd behavior because you'll be altering the view you iterate through.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension

```
{k:'+1-'+str(phoneBook[k]) for k in phoneBook}
```